# How to say "When did you tried this" in Mandarin?

Tags: translation

To explain the context, today I talked with a security officer down in my dormitory, and she gave me a picture of a food that she believed came from my country. I then wanted to ask her, "When did you try that?" by saying, but she did not understand it despite my trying to say it with the right tone three times. What is the mistake in my phrase, and how can I say "when did you try that" like a native Chinese?

And also, to add, how do natives usually call a security officer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to express "When did you try that?" like a native Chinese speaker, you can express as the follows.

你在哪里吃过这个？or 你什么时候吃过这个？

I prefer the first one, as we chinese often use 哪里 to question the occasion where the things happened, also including the time, the place...

Answer (score 1):

Use "eat" instead of "try"
你什么时候吃过这个？

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your question to "Officer, did you try/teste it before? When?" - "警衛, 妳以前嚐過它嗎? 什麼時候?"